# How to print the username, message and time together using javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I think that the problem i am facing is very silly, but still i am not able to understand how to fix it.

**Python Code:**

```
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect, session
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from time import localtime, strftime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "thisisthesecretkey"
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
socketio = SocketIO(app)

localtime = strftime('%b-%d %I:%M%p', localtime())

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.form.get('user')
        session["username"] = user
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")

@app.route("/chatroom")
def chatroom():
    return render_template("chatting.html")

@socketio.on('submit data')
def sample(data):
    selection = data["selection"]
    time_stamp = data["time_stamp"]
    emit("announce data", {"selection":selection, "time_stamp":time_stamp}, broadcast = True)


socketio.run(app)
```

**JS Code:**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  var socket = io.connect(
    location.protocol + "//" + document.domain + ":" + location.port
  );

  socket.on('connect', () => {
    document.querySelector('.submit-btn').onclick = () => {
      let today = new Date();
      let month = today.getMonth();
      let day = today.getDay();
      let hours = today.getHours();
      let minutes = today.getMinutes();
      document.querySelector(".submit-btn").onclick = () => {
        let today = new Date();
        let month = today.getMonth();
        let date = today.getDate();
        let hours = today.getHours();
        let minutes = today.getMinutes();
        let day = today.getDay();

        const monthNames = [
          "January",
          "February",
          "March",
          "April",
          "May",
          "June",
          "July",
          "August",
          "September",
          "October",
          "November",
          "December",
        ];

        let current_time = `${monthNames[today.getMonth()]} ${date}, ${hours}:${minutes}`;

        const selection = document.querySelector('.message-entered').value;
        socket.emit('submit data', {'selection':selection, 'time_stamp':current_time});
    }
    socket.on('announce data', data => {
      const p = document.createElement('p');
      p.innerHTML = `${data.selection}` + ` ` + `${data.time_stamp}`;
      document.querySelector('.displaying-message-div').append(p);

    });
  };
});
});
```

When something is entered in the input bar the result i get is **This is the sample text enteredJune 11, 19:13**. So i want to get a result in which the first line has message and the next line is time.

Answer (score 0):

@Pratham Dave

Try adding a break tag and place the values in spans:

```
 p.innerHTML = `<span>${data.selection}</span>` + `</br>` + `<span>${data.time_stamp}</span>`;
```

Comment: I updated my answer and tested it inside a p tag along with the break tag and it is giving the desired result.

Comment: @Pratham Dave that's good to hear, I'm glad I was able to help